Sum two columns in H2 using JPA
I am trying to perform a simple query that sums four columns for each element of a table.
I am using spring + jpa + junit with h2 for testing.
The select is something like this:
SELECT COL1 + COL2 + COL3 + COL4 AS PRICE FROM TABLEA

During the test using H2 I can see that the proposed SQL is deleting the "+" operator.
SELECT COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 AS PRICE FROM TABLEA

This is obviously wrong and the query syntax is not correct.
I have tried multiple methods to create the query, but it is always deleting the "+" operator.
Any ideas why is this happening? This is driving me crazy, I do not know how to solve it and I didnt see any post, even using AI to detect any errors in the query shows none (the query is validated using sqldeveloper with a Oracle19 database)
The columns are numeric type and not null.
Tried to force cast to number for each column, group the columns adding just two by two, reducing the sum to just two columns , changing the driver mode ,etc. but it keeps doing the delete of the "+".

how exactly are you trying to execute this query? What JPA provider are you using, and where (ie hibernate/spring etc)

I am using JPA with Spring.
I have tried with @NamedNativeQuery and directly with enitityManager.createNativeQuery + q.getSingleResult() .Both methods are deleting the "+"

If you are using Spring, you are probably using Hibernate and it is 'interpreting' your SQL and modifying it. I don't know why they do that to be honest, as other providers pass the SQL straight through. You can try another provider, or add the exact code you are using and tag the question as Hibernate and see if someone knows how to work around it
